# Access denied error when trying to start a GATT server in Jetson Nano

Tags: bluetooth, d-bus, bluez

I'm writing a GATT server application using [this article](https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/) as basis. My initial code runs fine on my Linux laptop, but fails on my Jetson Nano (running an nVIDIA-tweaked version of Ubuntu 18.04) with an `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied` error when trying to access the `bluetoothd` daemon through interface `org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable`.

This is clearly a permission error of some kind, because the code works fine on the Nano when running as `root`, but fails if executed under a non-`root` user.  I know that non-`root` users should be members of the `bluetooth` group in order to access the Bluetooth API, but that is already the case for my user, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, for some obscure reason, it's necessary to add an explicit access permission to the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable` interface in config file `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf` in order to programmatically access the Bluetooth interface through D-Bus in the Jetson Nano. This is likely a side-effect of nVIDIA's customization of the Ubuntu environment. See the snippet below for reference:

```xml
<policy user="root">
  <allow own="org.bluez"/>
  <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaPlayer1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Profile1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1"/>
  <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable"/> <!-- Added this -->
  <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>
  ...
```